# javascript variable that contains </script>

Tags: javascript

I need a little assistance.  I have to create a javascript string that contains more javascript that is then written to a div tag in the parent window.  The code is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var jstr2 = '';
jstr2 += '<script language="javascript">\n';
jstr2 += 'function doPagingProducts(str) {\n';
jstr2 += 'document.frmPagingProducts.PG.value = str\;\n';
jstr2 += 'document.frmPagingProducts.submit()\;\n';
jstr2 += 'return false\;\n';
jstr2 += '}\n';
jstr2 += '</script>\n';
jstr2 += '\n';
</script>
```

However the closing script tag in the created string actually close the javascript and I get errors such as:

```
Error: unterminated string literal
Line: 135, Column: 9 ( The </script> line before the end of the string.)
Source Code:
jstr2 += '
```

Is there any way I can prevent this issue..?

Many thanks for all your help.

Best Regards,
Paul

---

**edit**  I finally solved this problem by extracting the final `</script>` from the javascript string. I added a end tag where the script shows. Its messy, but it works. Many thanks for all your comments.

Comment: This is a legit question. As a web developer I like to put basic XSS attempts into my stored data on the site I work on - for example naming an entity "<script>alert('XSS');</script>"; it's not a comprehensive test by any means but it helps keep the frontend honest. I should be able to output JSON containing those strings in a script tag in the HTML without issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386575/why-js-cant-understand-string-script/23386677#23386677

Answer (score 19):

The *SCRIPT* tag is content agnostic, so the parser just keeps running through the content until it finds a */SCRIPT* sequence. When it does, it passes the content it's found to the JS environment for evaluation. That gives you your unterminated literal error because the sent content ends where your */SCRIPT* begins. (There is no terminating quote mark to be found for the JS parser).

Escaping the slash with backslash

```
jstr2 += "<\/script>";
```

or some other work-around hack breaks the trigger point in the sequence here and solves this problem (but still leaves you with some very dubious code).

Answer (score 6):

Write it as:

```
jstr2 += '<\/script>\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to split the string:

```
jstr2 += '<' + '/script>\n';
```

It's also better to comment out everything inside the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
    // your code here
//-->
</script>
```

Or in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // your code here
//]]>
</script>
```

Or in XHTML:

- same as HTML but #PCDATA instead of CDATA.

Comment: how is '</script>\n' different from '<' + '/script>\n' ?

Comment: @Matt — it doesn't look like a close tag to an HTML parser.

Comment: Don't split the string up and then concatenate. It is harder to read, takes longer to write, consumes more bytes and is slower to parse then just escaping the slash.

Comment: It is not better to comment out everything in the script. That is designed to protect Netscape 2 eta browsers from treating `<script>` as an unknown element and rendering the context as text. It won't stop `</script>` being treated as an end tag because, in HTML, the element contains CDATA so the code that looks like HTML comments is not treated as such.

Comment: Using CDATA flags won't help much in XHTML either - since almost nobody serves their content as `application/xhtml+xml` so it gets parsed as if it was HTML.

Comment: I have NEVER seen #PCDATA used.

Comment: @Ryan, neither have I, but it's in the docs.  @David, (1) you split the string because when you're working with server scripts it's better than having to double escape, which is nastier to write. (2) It also helps pages validate, which is important for SEO. (3) sort of true, again this ties into the validation

Comment: @David: It's best to use CDATA when your script is bug free and ready for production.  It gets rid of JS errors like `for(var i=0,n=2;i<n;i++)`, where sometimes errors are reported on the `<n` portion due to spacing.

Comment: If you're working with server scripts then (a) Use a proper template language or, failing that, use a quote mechanism which doesn't treat `\\` as an escape character. The approach recommended by Michiel Kalkman will also pass validation of HTML (and, incidentally, is the method recommended by the W3C Validation Service). Validation is rather less important for SEO then it is for just making pages work in browsers.

Comment: As for CDATA markers that helps if (and only if) you are using XHTML, but, as I said, that has nothing to do with the problem at hand since the document will be parsed as if it were HTML if it is served as text/html (which it more or less has to be for it to work in Internet Explorer)

Comment: `Validation is rather less important for SEO then it is for just making pages work` lmao.  wrong.  I don't want to comment on too much else, but your data is flawed.  The only SEO that really matters is for Google.

Comment: `that has nothing to do with the problem at hand` ... sighhh `(which it more or less has to be for it to work in Internet Explorer)` wrong again. double sighhh